# I used doReturn, why would Mockito still call real implementation inside anonymous class?

Tags: java, mockito, guava

Class I want to test:

```
import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;
import com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader;
import com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache;

public class Subject {

    private CacheLoader<String, String> cacheLoader = new CacheLoader<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public String load(String key)
                throws Exception {
            return retrieveValue(key);
        }
    };

    private LoadingCache<String, String> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .build(cacheLoader);

    public String getValue(String key) {
        return cache.getUnchecked(key);
    }

    String retrieveValue(String key) {
        System.out.println("I should not be called!");
        return "bad";
    }
}
```

Here's my test case

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SubjectTest {

    String good = "good";

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    private Subject subject;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        doReturn(good).when(subject).retrieveValue(anyString());
        assertEquals(good, subject.getValue("a"));
    }
}
```

I got

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :good
Actual   :bad
```

Comment: Can you make `retrieveValue` a public method and see whether it works?

Comment: @KDM still not working. thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mark Peters did a great job diagnosing and explaining the root cause. I can think of a couple workarounds:

- **Move cache (re)initialization into a separate method.**

  By calling `new CacheLoader` from within the spy, the anonymous inner class is created with a reference to the spy as the parent instance. Depending on your actual system under test, you may also benefit from getting the cache creation out of the constructor path, especially if there's any heavy initialization or loading involved.

  ```
  public class Subject {

    public Subject() {
      initializeCache();
    }

    private LoadingCache<String, String> cache;

    @VisibleForTesting
    void initializeCache() {
      cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(new CacheLoader<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public String load(String key) throws Exception {
          return retrieveValue(key);
        }
      });
    }

    /* ... */
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    subject.initializeCache();
    doReturn(good).when(subject).retrieveValue(anyString());
    assertEquals(good, subject.getValue("a"));
  }
  ```
- **Make a manual override.**

  The root cause of your trouble is that the spy instance is different from the original instance. By overriding a single instance in your test, you can change behavior without dealing with the mismatch.

  ```
  @Test
  public void test() {
    Subject subject = new Subject() {
      @Override public String getValue() { return "good"; }
    }
  }
  ```
- **Refactor.**

  Though you can go for full DI, you may be able to just add a testing seam to the value function:

  ```
  public class Subject {

    private CacheLoader<String, String> cacheLoader = new CacheLoader<String, String>() {
      @Override
      public String load(String key) throws Exception {
        return valueRetriever.apply(key);
      }
    };

    private LoadingCache<String, String> cache =
        CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(cacheLoader);

    Function<String, String> valueRetriever = new Function<String, String>() {
      @Override
      public String apply(String t) {
        System.out.println("I should not be called!");
        return "bad";
      }
    };

    public String getValue(String key) {
      return cache.getUnchecked(key);
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    subject = new Subject();
    subject.valueRetriever = (x -> good);
    assertEquals(good, subject.getValue("a"));
  }
  ```

  Naturally, depending on your needs, `valueRetriever` could be an entirely separate class, or you could accept an entire `CacheLoader` as a parameter.

Answer (score 10):

This comes down to the implementation of the spy.  According to the [docs](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Spy.html), the Spy is created as a *copy* of the real instance:

> Mockito *does not* delegate calls to the passed real instance, instead it actually creates a copy of it. So if you keep the real instance and interact with it, don't expect the spied to be aware of those interaction and their effect on real instance state. The corollary is that when an *unstubbed* method is called *on the spy* but *not on the real instance*, you won't see any effects on the real instance.

It seems to be a *shallow* copy.  As a result, as far as my debugging shows, the `CacheLoader` is shared between the copy and the original object, but its reference to its enclosing object is the original object, not the spy.  Therefore the real `retrieveValue` is called instead of the mocked one.

I'm not sure offhand what the best way to resolve this would be.  One way for this specific example would be to invert the `CacheLoader` dependency (i.e. pass it into `Subject` instead of `Subject` defining it internally), and mock that instead of `Subject`.

Comment: Thanks A lot. I am currently just trying to accept the fact that I can't use _doReturn()_ to mock the entire method, and mock things I have inside the _retriveValue()_ method instead. I'd still like to see if someone can come up with a smart solution to make this work. Thanks.

Comment: @ssgao: In case you missed it, I did suggest one route that didn't involve mocking `getValue` (to use Dependency Injection, which is almost always used in conjunction with mocking).  I think the reason you're not finding a "smart" solution is because partial mocking is typically a design smell in itself.  It's better to break your unit dependencies first.  Mockito has a standard sermon on this: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#16

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, for Mockito 1.9.5 possible solution may be to change method visibility to "protected". Honestly, I have no idea how it works, but still, error gone.